# Why custom Where() implementation is slower than a LINQ Where()

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I wrote my `Where()` implementation:

```
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> MyWhere<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
    {
        using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (!enumerator.MoveNext()) throw new InvalidOperationException("Sequence contains no elements");            
            do
            {
                var candidate = enumerator.Current;
                if (predicate(candidate))
                    yield return candidate;
            }
            while (enumerator.MoveNext());
        }
    }
```

and compare its perfomance with LINQ `Where()`:

```
        var data = new int[1000000];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            data[i] = int.MaxValue;
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        // My Where() test
        stopwatch.Start();
        var res2 = data.MyWhere(x => x == int.MaxValue).ToList();
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedTicks);

        stopwatch.Reset();

        // LINQ Where() test
        stopwatch.Start();
        var res = data.Where(x => x == int.MaxValue).ToList();
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedTicks);
```

and got the following result:

```
124487
 50827
```

Help me understand, why `MyWhere()` implementation is too slow? What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: do you have consistent results if you swap the order of tests (LINQ native first) ? Also, which .NET version are you using ?

Comment: The Linq methods are designed to take advantage of certain types like `ICollection` to be more efficient.  FYI, `Where` doesn't throw on an empty collection (not sure if that's why you wrote your own or not).

Comment: You might find Jon Skeet's [Edulinq](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/edulinq/) posts useful.

Comment: @Pac0 yes, i swap them and have "swaped" result (69748 and 136629)

Comment: Your benchmark results are also influenced by time spent on garbage collection. Instead of using .ToList(), just use .Count() to eliminate that factor. Doing that will most like make difference in performance between your and LINQ code even bigger.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Judge your concern yourself checking the reference source for [`WhereArrayIterator`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,ed14299f42af7eb2,references)

Iterators are specialized for some concrete types like typed arrays and `List<T>` which positively affects the efficiency when it comes to access some given `IEnumerable<T>` elements.

For example, see this part of [`Enumerable.Where`](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs):

```
if (source is Iterator<TSource>) return ((Iterator<TSource>)source).Where(predicate);
if (source is TSource[]) return new WhereArrayIterator<TSource>((TSource[])source, predicate);
if (source is List<TSource>) return new WhereListIterator<TSource>((List<TSource>)source, predicate);
return new WhereEnumerableIterator<TSource>(source, predicate);
```

Comment: It would be interesting to know what's behind the downvote so I can improve my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @HelloWorld No problem ;) I'm glad you solved your concern!